# Why do I get Android : The target server failed to respond?

Tags: android, api, http, httpresponse

API Link : `http://www.familybuds.com/storegrunt-new/api_home/validate_step_one/platform/1`

POST parameter : `store_name = "abc"` the code is on GoDaddy Server

This api was working fine till 25July, but suddenly it stopped working from 26th morning on Android APP. The same api is working fine on iPhone APP.

**Android Code:**

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000+12000);

DefaultHttpClient  client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

HttpResponse response; 
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {              

        @Override
        public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)
                throws HttpException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!request.containsHeader("Accept-Encoding")) {
                request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            }
        }

    });

client.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {

        public void process(
                final HttpResponse response,
                final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                Header ceheader = entity.getContentEncoding();
                if (ceheader != null) {
                    HeaderElement[] codecs = ceheader.getElements();
                    for (int i = 0; i < codecs.length; i++) {
                        if (codecs[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                            response.setEntity(
                                    new GzipDecompressingEntity(response.getEntity()));
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }               


    });

// Log.d(TAG, "Executing request: "+ methodToString(mMethod) +": "+ mUri.toString());
response = client.execute(httppost);
```

**Stack trace(Log) for android:**

```
07-26 16:24:28.031: W/System.err(13642): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
07-26 16:24:28.089: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
07-26 16:24:28.097: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
07-26 16:24:28.097: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
07-26 16:24:28.101: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
07-26 16:24:28.105: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
07-26 16:24:28.105: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
07-26 16:24:28.105: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
07-26 16:24:28.105: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
07-26 16:24:28.109: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-26 16:24:28.113: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-26 16:24:28.113: W/System.err(13642):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-26 16:24:28.117: W/System.err(13642):    at com.webhelper.WebApiRequest.performJSon(WebApiRequest.java:111)
07-26 16:24:28.121: W/System.err(13642):    at com.webhelper.HttpHelper.doInBackground(HttpHelper.java:171)
07-26 16:24:28.121: W/System.err(13642):    at com.webhelper.HttpHelper.doInBackground(HttpHelper.java:1)
07-26 16:24:28.124: W/System.err(13642):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-26 16:24:28.124: W/System.err(13642):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-26 16:24:28.128: W/System.err(13642):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-26 16:24:28.128: W/System.err(13642):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-26 16:24:28.128: W/System.err(13642):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-26 16:24:28.132: W/System.err(13642):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Have tried out solution from : [Https connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216209/https-connection-android) but with no luck..

I tried putting the same server code on Amazon EC2 Server.. and API worked fine with android and iPhone APP.

Can anyone help, what may be the reason for sudden non-working of Android app for communicating with server(API) on GoDaddy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000+12000);


DefaultHttpClient  client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
```

**Try replacing above code with this**

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000+12000);


DefaultHttpClient  client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httpost.setParams(httpParameters);
```

**This solution worked for me....**

Comment: This is works for me. I have same problem since 25 july 2014.

Comment: Hi @Dharni, I had same problem and it has been resolved by your answer. Can you please state why this change is require now as it was working fine before?